# How to get value of SelectBox when using AppEngine in Java, JavaScript and HTML

Tags: java, javascript, html, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a way of filtering data that is stored within the datastore. The method I am using for this is a mixture of HTML, Javascript and Java Servlets. A form is made that allows data that is input into the Web Application to be sent to the Java Servlet. The Servlet then does the required actions and sends the user back to the page with the updated data. My problem is I have to use a SelectBox within this form that allows the user to select the atribute they wish to filter by, e.g. title, author. When the submit button is pressed, the value of the SelectBox is not sent as a parameter. This means a ERROR 500 appears as there isn't enough parameters to perform the function. I need to:-

1. Get the value of the SelectBox.
2. Pass it to the function with the parameter value in a text field. (Almost Completed)
3. Set the value of idvBook to equal the List that is sent back to the Webb Application.

Firstly, this is how I am creating the form with the SelectBox, TextInput and ButonInput:-

```
<div class="headline">Filter the DataStore</div>
    <div class="info">To view individual records, select the attribute 
    you'd like to filter by and enter the value you'd like to find. Click 
    the button to generate the table based on your search criteria.</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         function filter(){
             document.filterBooks.action="/get";
             var idvBook = document.filterBooks.submit();
         }
    </script>
    <form name="filterBooks">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="attribute">Attribute</label></td>
                <td>
                    <select id="attributeSelect">
                        <option value="void">Select Attribute</option>
                        <option value="id">ID</option>
                        <option value="title">Title</option>
                        <option value="author">Author</option>
                        <option value="publisher">Publisher</option>
                    </select>

                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top"><label for="value">Value</label></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="value" id="value"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Filter" onclick="filter()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Book ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Publisher</th>
            <th>Publish Date</th>
            <th>Remove Book</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            for (Book book : idvBook) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=book.getId()%></td>
            <td><%=book.getTitle()%></td>
            <td><%=book.getDescription()%></td>
            <td><%=book.getAuthor()%></td>
            <td><%=book.getPublisher()%></td>
            <td><%=book.getPublishDate()%></td>
            <td><a class="done" href="/done?id=<%=book.getId()%>">Remove</a></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Once this has been made, it is then placed in the HTML table located below the form (shown in the code above).

This sends the parameters to this servlet:-

```
public class ServletGetBooks extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException 
    {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
        String attribute = request.getParameter("attributeSelect").toString();
        String param = request.getParameter("value");
        Dao.INSTANCE.getBooks(attribute, param);
        resp.sendRedirect("/TodoApplication.jsp");
    }
}
```

You can see another function is ran here. This function looks like this:-

```
public List<Book> getBooks(String attribute, String param) {
    EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
   Query q = null;

    if(attribute.equals("id"))
    {
        q = em.createQuery("select b from Book b where b.id = :id");
        q.setParameter("id", param);
    }
    else if(attribute.equals("title"))
    {
        q = em.createQuery("select b from Book b where b.title = :title");
        q.setParameter("title", param);
    }
    else if(attribute.equals("author"))
    {
        q = em.createQuery("select b from Book b where b.author = :author");
        q.setParameter("author", param);
    }
    else if(attribute.equals("publisher"))
    {
        q = em.createQuery("select b from Book b where b.publisher = :publisher");
        q.setParameter("publisher", param);
    }
    List<Book> books = q.getResultList();
    return books;
}
```

How can i get it so that i can get the value of the SelectBox, run the function and set the result of this to equal idvBook?

EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I'll simplify things. I need this within <% ... %> tags:-

```
List<Book> idvBook = new ArrayList<Book>();
idvBook = dao.getBook("Value in SelectBox","Value in TextInput");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select box does not have a name attribute and its value is thus not sent with the form data.